# XNA Texture2D List outOfRangeException

Tags: c#, xna

first of all, i am new to xna. Trying to craete blackjack game. And i have created 2 lists  to add random card to the list. But i cannot understand why doesnt it add pics to the list tekstuur2

Heres code :

```
public class Kaart
    {

        public Vector2 asukoht = new Vector2(0, 0);

        public List<Texture2D> tekstuur = new List<Texture2D>();
        public List<Texture2D> tekstuur2 = new List<Texture2D>();

        Random  rand = new Random();
        public void loadContent2(ContentManager manager2)
        {



            for (int x = 3; x < 7; x++)

                tekstuur2.Add(manager2.Load<Texture2D>("Risti" + x.ToString()));

        }

        public void loadContent(ContentManager manager)
        {

            for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++)



                tekstuur.Add(manager.Load<Texture2D>("Risti" + j.ToString()));

        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sprite)
        {

            sprite.Draw(tekstuur[rand.Next(tekstuur.Count)], asukoht, Color.White);
            sprite.Draw(tekstuur2[rand.Next(tekstuur2.Count)], asukoht, Color.White); 
// an error occurs (ArgumentOutofRangeException) , tekstuur2.count = 0 at that point, but at the tekstuur.Count it is 4.

        }

    }
}
```

Heres another class where these methods are called :

```
namespace WindowsGame1
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Vector2 koht = new Vector2(0,0);

    Kaart yks;
    Kaart kaks;


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        yks = new Kaart();
        kaks = new Kaart();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        //kaardi laadimine 
        yks.loadContent(this.Content);
        kaks.loadContent2(this.Content);


        // yhe kaarti asukoht
        yks.asukoht.X = 100;
        yks.asukoht.Y = 300;
        // teise kaardi asukoht
        kaks.asukoht.X = 200;
        kaks.asukoht.Y = 400;



        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();



        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // kaartide joonistamine 
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        yks.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        kaks.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

        spriteBatch.End();

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you call the loadContent2?

Comment: I call it out at the Game1 class, which is autogenerated by xna, loadContent method. I call both of these methods there, for the first card and second card.

Comment: are you sure is being called? can you put a breakpoint inside loadContent2 to see if it's being called? if it is being called than check for reference of tekstuur2 outside the class Kart, it may be that you either clear the list or assign a new one.

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem is you should call for every instance of Kaart (in your case yks and kaks) loadContent AND loadContent2
this in your method LoadContent:

```
    //kaardi laadimine 
    yks.loadContent(this.Content);
    kaks.loadContent2(this.Content);
```

become:

```
    //kaardi laadimine 
    yks.loadContent(this.Content);
    yks.loadContent2(this.Content);
    kaks.loadContent2(this.Content);
    kaks.loadContent(this.Content);
```

note that since the texture are the same there's no need to use two different list for containing them, you can do this in your Kaart Draw method:

```
sprite.Draw(tekstuur[rand.Next(tekstuur.Count)], asukoht, Color.White);
sprite.Draw(tekstuur[rand.Next(tekstuur.Count)], asukoht, Color.White);
```

this way you have to only call LoadContent.

Another note:
at the moment you're instantiating a Random rand; the problem with that is that sequential instantiation of this class (in a short time) is not recommended and your two KArt are going to use the same random texture. To resolve this make the Random rand a static variable:

```
private static Random  rand = new Random();
```